# Python : Transposing a column with multiple values in each row into column headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data

```
Date            Name       Salary        Models
01/01/2019      Jack       50,000        AC, GM, MC
01/01/2019      Sam        30,000        AC, KL
01/01/2019      Los        45,000        GM
```

I need to transpose the column Models but each model(separated by comma) should be a column.
Expected output is

```
Date            Name       Salary     AC     GM     MC      KL     GM
01/01/2019      Jack       50,000     1      1      1       0      0   
01/01/2019      Sam        30,000     1      0      0       1      0   
01/01/2019      Los        45,000     0      0      0       0      1
```

I tried the pandas.dummies.
 `df1 = pandas.get_dummies(df, columns=['Models'])`

But the problem is I don't know how to split the models in each row based on the comma and then do the pandas.dummies. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your expected output looks incorrect. There are two `GM` columns, and the last row doesn't have any `1`'s.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I updated it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.get_dummies`:

```
df.drop('Models',axis=1).join(df.Models.str.get_dummies(', '))
```

Output:

```
         Date  Name  Salary  AC  GM  KL  MC
0  01/01/2019  Jack  50,000   1   1   0   1
1  01/01/2019   Sam  30,000   1   0   1   0
2  01/01/2019   Los  45,000   0   1   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
temp_df = pd.concat([df['Models'].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1)
```

to separate the values in the Models column, and then by using

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(temp_df, columns=temp_df.columns)
```

getting the desired result.